# Modify keys in multiple nested objects/arrays

Tags: arrays, json, nested, jq

I want to modify the value of all `x` keys in a json that looks like:

```json
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": [
        {
          "0": {
            "x": 23,
            "name": "AS"
          }
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "x": 23,
            "name": "AS"
          }
        },
        {
          "2": {
            "x": 23,
            "name": "Fe"
          }
        },
        {
          "3": {
            "x": 23,
            "name": "Pl"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried multiple approaches, but I can't modify the value of `x` and obtain the full json as a result. All I managed to do is modify the value of `x` and obtain the last array as a result.

Here is the closest I have been to achieve the result: https://jqplay.org/s/Wx741btZOg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `|=` one can simply perform the update by writing:

```
.a.b.c |= [.[]|.[].x=97]
```

or perhaps more clearly:

```
.a.b.c |= map(.[].x=97)
```

If you really do want to "modify the value of all x keys", then you could use `walk`:

```
walk(if type == "object" and has("x") then .x=97 else . end)
```

(If your jq does not have `walk`, then you can snarf its def from the web, e.g. from [builtin.jq](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedolan/jq/master/src/builtin.jq) )

Answer (score 1):

To change all `x` values to `97`, you can try this jq command:

```
<file jq '.a.b.c as $in | .a.b.c=[ $in[] | .[].x=97 ]'
```

The command stores the parent of the object in the variable `$in` such that you can modify one of its sub element.